# How to set transform rotation to absolute 90 degrees without float imperfection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I plan to rotate a GameObject around 90 degrees using a specific axis via script in an instant, but every attempt resulted in a float inperfection.

The GameObject I want to rotate has a mesh collider applied. The parent parent object has different scales for its axis. Thus I should have a responsive collider that adjusts to its GameObjects scale. Apllying the rotation using the unity editor results in the wished effects.

On the other hand I've tried several ways to created these effect using a script file. But they all result in the same problem.

```
gameObject.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);

gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);

gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);

gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 90);
```

Expected: A perfect 90 degree rotation. Working collider.
Result: A rotation of 90.00001 degrees. Buggy collider.

Comment: A difference of 0.00001 should not affect the operation of a collider in Unity. Look elsewhere in your project for the problem.

Comment: You can't .. as you say yourself it is due to `float` imprecision .. the round `90` you see in the Inspector is just a "beautified" value but under the hood it will result in the same effective value. In which way does it make your collider "buggy"?

Comment: set using code: https://imgur.com/5fKl0fN

Comment: set using editor: https://imgur.com/k85AiQe

Comment: the colider only aligns if the rotation %90 equals 0